# Javascript transitions on CSS scaled images perform poorly

Tags: javascript, css, performance, scaling, fading

I am working on a front page gallery which has several images, **scaled to fit the page via CSS**.

The images **fade** from one to the next (overtop of each other), and will resize if the user resizes the browser to use up the space.

The problem is that the image fading performs terribly on most browsers and on all but the newest computers.

**However, if the images are not stretched, then the performance is perfect across all browsers on most computers.**

I've run into this problem before with other sites I've designed and have spent considerable amount of time researching and testing solutions, but I can't seem to find anything.

Any ideas?

---

I've implemented a performance/styling trade-off. Instead of arbitrarily scaling the images, say by a factor of 0.7543234, I round it to 8 and so on. I found that arbitrary scaling factors have a huge performance penalty, and using single decimal scaling greatly reduces that.

Here is some js code:

```
var adjustedNewWidth = Math.round((roundNumber( (newWidth / originalImage.width), 1)+0.1)*originalImage.width);

var adjustedNewHeight = Math.round((roundNumber( (newHeight / originalImage.height), 1)+0.1)*originalImage.height);
```

- newWidth is the desired width,
- originalImage.width is my array where
  I keep the original image sizes
  (since js is so smart it can't access
  these after it's been scaled),
- roundNumebr is a function which
  scales to the nearest decimal place

`function roundNumber(num, dec) {
 var result = Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,dec))/Math.pow(10,dec);
 return result;
}`

After this the fading works about 50% better but is still not perfect. Well thanks for your help everyone hopefully this helps someone out there.

Comment: I don't see any mark up, but I've worked with JQuery plugins like:

http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/default.php

http://devkick.com/lab/fsgallery/

and have never experienced a degradation with image quality when browsers are resized unless the computer is already taxed by other systems.

Would you mind sharing some code.

Comment: It is actually evident on that link you sent me. The code in the link modifies the image to be 100% height, and 100% width, and sets the a tag around it to be something like width: 1462px; height: 1096.5px;.

Perhaps the browser you are using is too fast or your computer is too fast. Try it in Firefox (the newest browser) or IE if you have it available. Also resize your browser to the maximum size. 

On my computer here it is very slow and jumpy, and I am running a 2ghz Core2Duo mac mini

Comment: I've tested in Chrome, Ie9, FireFox and Opera and they are all smooth. Testing it in a Virtual machine running other browsers I can see what you are talking about. Unfortunately I don't think there is a clean way around this except for limiting the math JS has to do. JS doesn't do a good job with a lot of math/trig so I'd recommend using whole numbers, or only 1 decimal point when doing minor calculations to avoid performance degradation.

Comment: Yes this was the solution I implemented above. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The performence loss due to the way browsers scale and display information and pictures.

Try adding the following to anything that will be scaled:

```
-ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
```

This turned off filtering while the image is being scaled making it much faster on slow machines.

After the animation is complete, set the element's styles to:

```
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
```

Also the rounding script seems to invoke Math a lot when rounding, this is quite slow when repeated many times (like in an animation). You could cut down the overhead by replacing the rounding script with this leaner version:

```
var roundNumber = function (num) {
    return ~~(num + .5);
    //this take a number (num), adds .5, then chops off the decimal place. 
}
```